# Close "technique" question? tricky one

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Should this be closed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109768/creating-hand-animation-with-unity

This question is not really "answers could be opinion" (there's one and only one specific clear direct answer, I gave it in a few words in the comment) --

but it just doesn't seem like an SO question.

What's the deal here?

Comment: Seems like a technique question to me.  I'd suggest that you just vote as you think appropriate and let the system work. No real need to raise it here.

Comment: Cheers Bra, When you say "Seems like a technique question to me" do you mean ......... "technique questions should be closed"?  That's what I'm asking.  ie, did you in fact click "Close" on it?

Comment: _Technique questions_ may turn out _too broad_ or _opinion based_ or even _asking for 3rd party resources_.

Comment: okie dokey ....

Comment: I really want to know though, **Should technique questions be closed?**  (indeed in this specific example -- it is not broad, not opinion based, and not asking-for-3rd-party-stuff)

Answer (score 4):

This question for me moves into the realm where a Unity question becomes non-programming-related. Unless there is a clear indication that all this needs to be scripted, I'd say it's off-topic.

A question like this should simply be asked on Unity's Answers site or their forums. I don't know Gamedev.SE well enough to make a recommendation there.

So overall, to me this isn't programming related enough to stay.

Comment: that works for me, thanks Bart.  like you say a key seems to be **does it come down to scripting**